# When is it safe to call `measureInWindow`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, lifecycle

I'm trying to figure out at what point in a component lifecycle I can call `measureInWindow` on a view and be guaranteed to get the right values back. For example:

```js
const Measure = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef();

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    ref.current.measureInWindow((x, y) => {
      // y is 0
    })
  });

  return <View ref={ref} />;
};
```

I get `0` for `y` in the above example, rather than `88` which is the right value because the navigation bar is that tall. If I put the `measureInWindow` call inside a `setTimeout` with `0ms` then I get the correct value back.

I have also tried using using `useEffect` instead of `useLayoutEffect` and I get the same result.

**EDIT**

A comment on this post got me looking at the [`onLayout`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#onlayout) prop for `View`. My initial tests indicate that I can call `measureInWindow` successfully there. However, I'd still like to find some concrete documentation beyond just my cursory testing.

```js
<View
  ref={ref}
  onLayout={e => {
    ref.current.measureInWindow((x, y) => {
      console.log('onLayout', y);
    });
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Never worked with react-native before, but this is what I found online: "Note that these measurements are not available until after the rendering has been completed in native. If you need the measurements as soon as possible, consider using the onLayout prop instead." - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation#other-native-methods

Comment: That's a good thought, but that also provides me with `0` for the `y` value.

Comment: @GennadyDogaev looks like calling `measureInWindow` inside the `onLayout` callback works! Still hoping to find clear documentation confirming that this is a bulletproof approach though.